# How to get the number of features from a fitted scikit-learn model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to extract the number of features from a model after I had fitted this model to my data.

I have looked through the model's directory and found ways to get the number only for specific models (e.g. looking at the dimensions of support vectors for SVM), but I didn't find a general way I could use for any type of a model.

Say I have my dataset of instances and corresponding classes

```py
X, y    # dataset
```

and use an arbitrary model from the `scikit-learn` library to fit this data

```py
model.fit(X,y)
```

Later I want to use this model to find the dimensions of the original dataset, something in the way of

```
model.n_features_
```

Is there a quick and general way to do this?

Comment: A hackish way to so is to inject your own custom member to any model instance that you create and train, for example:
clf.__my_num_features = ...

Comment: @InonPeled That is quite a good idea. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no single common attribute for all classifier in Sklearn.

I would recommend the following:

For any `sklearn.linear_model`/`sklearn.svm.svc`, you can use the following approach.

```
>>> clf.coef_.shape[-1]
```

For any tree based models (`DecisionTreeClassifier`/`RandomForestClassifier`/`GradientBoostingClassifier`), you can use

```
>>> clf.n_features_
```

**Update**:

New in **version 1.0**.

`n_features_in_`: int

> Number of features seen during fit.

`feature_names_in_`:

> Names of features seen during fit. Defined only when X has feature names that are all strings.